# I cannot remove bayonet bulb from a wall fitting. It keeps turning around and turning the copper bulb holder with it

Tags: repair

I a light that has been put on a wall outside the kitchen to light up the back yard.It is connected directly to the electric supply.
It stopped working. So I wonder what could have gone wrong,power is still on I do not know how to go about fixing it. Please help.

Comment: Did the light bulb burn out?  What do you mean "connected directly to the electric supply" (no light switch?)?  What kind of light is it (motion-detecting security light, or a "regular" light that is on all the time)?    If you cannot get the bulb out, how do you know power is "still on"?  We need more information to help you out.

Comment: One more thing.  I fail to see the connection between the title of your post and the actual question.  Would you please clarify what the problem is and/or what you want help doing?  A good place to start on making good titles and questions is the SE FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details, as noted by @tnknepp. Without more details (maybe even some pics so we can see what you're seeing), it's impossible to answer your question because there are far too many possibilities. Without these details, you question will probably be closed - if that happens before you return, you can still [edit] it, and it will likely be reopened.

Comment: "She's the pride of the neighborhood, She's the raw flame,
The **live wire**" Josie, by Steely Dan.